# Why does this problem only have one solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

My problem: $$x^{2/3} - x^{1/3} - 6 = 0$$

Let $k = x^{1/3}$, which simplifies the problem to $k^2 - k - 6 = 0$, allowing the solutions $k = 3$ and $k = - 2$ to be found on inspection.

From there I plugged X back in to $k=3$, which nicely solves to give $x = 27$

However, In the case of $k = - 2$ $\\$
$( x^{1/3} = -2)$, It appears to solve to give $x = - 8$, but when I plug -8 back into the original equation it does not work and I am at a loss as to why, could someone please explain?

Edit to clarify: only interested in real solutions:
[image: graph]

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Not all the roots In an quadratic equation are acceptable. We must check and then reject the in-admisible.

Comment: My check shows that $x=-8$ does work!

Comment: @HocNgo not in the original equation, I checked with a calculator and wolfram alpha

Comment: $(-8)^{2/3} = (64)^{1/3} = 4$, $(-8)^{1/3} = -2$, so we get $4 -(-2)-6 = 0.$

Comment: @Cursed1701 wolfram alpha only looks at the positve part of the graph, you have to specify that you want all real-valued roots, then it gives -8 too, I just checked.

Comment: One should always rely first on one's brain and then on a machine. (no offence intended).

Comment: Here's the normal [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E(2%2F3)-x%5E(1%2F3)-6+from+-10+to+10&rawformassumption=%22%5E%22+-%3E+%22Real%22) a bit shortened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(-8)^{2/3}=4 \\ 
(-8)^{1/3}=-2 \\
4 -(-2) -6 = 6 - 6 =0$

What seems to be the problem with the solution?

Edit: accidentally wrote + instead of - , my apologies.

Comment: just added plot from wolfram and added clarification to question: only interested in real solutions, and the function does not appear to exist with negative x values... but i am confused why

Comment: @Cursed1701 notice the statement at the beginning of the calculation in Wolfram : "Assuming the **principal root** | Use the **real‐valued root** instead"
When you choose that option you will get the entire graph, because a principal root is always nonnegative.

Comment: @DomoB Ahhh thank you for explaining, this had confused me so much!

Comment: @Cursed1701 no problem, happy to help. :)